# Basic Authentication With XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, basic-authentication

I am attempting to use XMLHTTPRequest to get an update on twitter.

```
var XMLReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
XMLReq.open("GET", "http://twitter.com/account/verify_credentials.json", false, "TestAct", "password");
XMLReq.send(null);
```

However, using my sniffer I cannot see any authorization headers being passed through.  Hence, I get a 401 error response from Twitter.

The account and password are correctly entered.

Anyone attempt this?  Can anyone give me some pointers?  Thank you.

Answer (score 79):

You just need to add a Authorization header, a user name and password in a  base64 encoded string as follows.

```
XMLReq.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
```

Comment: Should the `client` in the code snippet be `XMLReq` (the variable from the question)?

Comment: Actualy, Yes you are correct. The method is XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader(header, value).

Answer (score 10):

In cross-origin requests, you have to explicitly set the `withCredentials` flag if you want user credentials to be sent.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-withcredentials-attribute (where [user credentials](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#user-credentials) includes HTTP authentication)

Comment: New links are https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-withcredentials-attribute and https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#user-credentials

Answer (score 3):

Due to the *Origin policy*, you cannot make a XMLHttpRequest from your domain to another domain.  E.g. you cannot use `http://twitter.com/...` URLs unless your script was loaded from `twitter.com`. If your script is loaded from `http://localhost/`, the AJAX request also need to go to localhost.

Comment: You _can_ make XHR requests to another server, but that other server must set CORS headers for the request to not be rejected by the browser you're using (unless your using a dodgy browser that ignores the lack of CORS headers).