# JavaScript XMLHttpRequest vs curl

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl, xmlhttprequest

using curl I can send a POST request to

"http://myusername:mypassword@SomeURL" to trigger an action

Using xml http request I've tried doing the same thing but running the following code:

```
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", "http://myusername:mypassword@SomeURL", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  xhttp.send();
```

Greets me with the error:

POST http://myusername:mypassword@SomeURL 403 (Forbidden)

Now why would this be ? Is accessing an url like this via a browser, curl, arc... etc different from accessing it via .js ? 
Furthermore I've tried posting to said url using the action of a form and it worked swimmingly, but I'd prefer to get things done in JavaScript if possible for this specific task.

So... ahm, any ideas ? The documentation behind the XMLHttpRequest that i've seen has been rather lack-luster for a technology that "carries the modern web upon its shoulders".

Comment: CURL is a get call I guess, besides I did not understand the usage of **:** in the url that you are requesting

Comment: the specific API I'm calling read those header as being a username and a password, it uses the ':' to see where the split is (or at least I assume that's what it does). Think of the myusername:mypassword as being a single "user" header.

Answer (score 0):

Necessary reading to solve this question:

- [Basic Authentication With XMLHTTPRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652178/basic-authentication-with-xmlhttprequest)
- [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)

I am deliberately not adding a code sample; the linked questions have everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need to [enable CORS](https://enable-cors.org/resources.html) (cross-origin resource sharing)