# Javascript - XmlHttpRequest.Send with credentials (user name and password)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, basic-authentication, digest-authentication

xhr.open(...) with username and password works only when the script is at the same domain as the URI. This appears to be due to the so-called *same origin policy*. As one would note from this answer [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652178/basic-authentication-with-xmlhttprequest#), one can send an explicit Authorization header with the xhr request, thus bypassing the *same origin policy*.

The question is why do we then have this *same origin policy* that can, with little effort, be bypassed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a little thing called `CORS` would stand in your way, so you're not really bypassing anything

Comment: Why would then a browser refuse to send XHR credentials to the server that is on a different domain? It could simply let them through - since they can be sent through the Authorization header anyway.

Comment: setting user/password in `open` (not `send` as your question implies) doesn't add an Authorization header. Given a domain `http://example.com/` `.open('GET', '/path/resource.ext', false, 'user', 'password')` would result in the request `http://user:password@example.com/path/resource.ext`

Comment: Thanks! Yet, the browser refuses to send the request implied by .open('GET', '/path/resource.ext', false, 'user', 'password') but one can still do  .open('GET', '/path/resource.ext', false) with .setRequestHeader("Authorization", "blahblah"). Why does the browser refuse the former?

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Comment: No, I didn't find an answer.