# 401 error using HTTP basic auth with Axios in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, http, authentication, axios, basic-authentication

I'm working on a Vuejs app that gets its data from an Apache Solr index, and I have had my app working with the index using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to make the connection. However, HTTP basic authentication has been added, and I am unable to get authentication to work. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is set on the server (it worked prior to adding the auth to the index), so that is not an issue. I am attempting to use the `auth` object in the config object in `axios.get()` like  so:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams()
params.append('fl', 'label,bundle,entity_id,ss_language,url,is_product_slideshow')
  if (this.nodeType) {
    params.append('fq', 'bundle:' + this.nodeType)
  } else {
    params.append('fq', 'bundle:' + '(article OR document OR video OR product_display)')
  }
  params.append('fq', 'ss_language:' + this.language)
  params.append('fq', 'bs_status:' + 1)
  params.append('fq', '-is_field_restricted_to_internal_use:1')
  params.append('fq', '-is_field_restricted_to_author_of_as:1')
  params.append('fq', '-is_field_pp_confidential:1')
  params.append('fq', '-is_field_pp_do_not_show_item_on_t:1')
  params.append('q', qs)
  params.append('sort', 'is_sort asc')
  params.append('wt', 'json')
  params.append('rows', 10)
  params.append('start', queryStartRows)
  axios.get('https://my-solr-url.com/solr/my-solr-index/select', {
    params: params,
    withCredentials: true,
    auth: {
      username: 'myusername',
      password: 'mypassword'
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    this.results = response.data.response.docs
    var numFound = this.numFound = response.data.response.numFound
    // Calculate last page.
    var numFoundRounded = Math.floor(numFound / 10) * 10
    var numPages = numFoundRounded / 10
    this.lastPage = numPages
  })
```

I can get the query to run fine from Postman, so I know I have the correct credentials.

From what I can tell from the docs and other examples, I'm doing it right, but I'm still getting a 401 error.

I also use this index from a Drupal site, and there, the user id and password are passed as part of the URL:

```
https://myusername:mypassword@my-solr-url.com/solr/my-solr-index/select?...
```

but that approach doesn't work here, either. What do I need to do differently to get the authentication to work?

Comment: You are mixing data with config in the axios request. The config object should be the third argument of the `get` request: `axios.get('http://example.com', {}, { auth: {...} })`

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

```
axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://my-solr-url.com/solr/my-solr-index/select',
    params: params,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers:{Authorization:'Basic '+BASE64ENCODED(USERNAME+':'+PASSWORD)}
})
```

You must provide base64 encoded username+':'+password for authorization and try.

Comment: I tried it that way, and got `GET http://localhost:8080/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)` I also tried just `axios({method:'get',url: 'https://my-solr-url.com/solr/my-solr-index/select')}`, and that still gives me the 401 error.

Comment: i have updated my code can you try the updated one? and tell me the response? also if you are sending the request from a web app then open the developer tool of the browser and see the request headers sent to server and compare with postman headers.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mentioned above that I tried (I tried it again, just to make sure). It gives me the 401 error.

Comment: @wonder95 will you try my updated answer? for testing you can try any online tool to convert your `USERNAME+':'+PASSWORD` to `base64` encoded string and then put it on Authorization header.

Comment: Trying that code gives me the same 401 error. Postman was actually sending that header, so I was able to just copy paste from there (although I did verify with another encoding tool). I don't get it.

Comment: you should try to send the request with `XMLHttpRequest` and see how it works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652178/basic-authentication-with-xmlhttprequest if it still does not work then it may be a general error if it works then `axios` may have some problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue as you described with an ExpressJS app; Axios with `auth: {username: 'user', password: 'pass'}` being rejected with 401 from Axios client in browser, but 200 OK from Postman.  You mention you're setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, I was able to resolve the issue by ensuring the `CORS` middleware was executed before the `auth` middleware.  I noticed that my Axios client sends an HTTP `OPTIONS` request before the `GET` request that was causing the browser to block based on CORS policy.

For those wondering how to manually calculate the base64 encoded string per @Inus' suggestion, the [`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) JS method could be used, but in-browser this still gave me a 401 (as expected) as this is equivalent to Axios' calculated Authorization header when using the `auth` property.